What sort of gate can I put on these outdoor stairs?
I need to put a gate to prevent my 3 year old from walking up these outdoor stairs and hurting herself on the roof.

However, I expect that I should or could not drill into either the stairs or the siding of the house. Is there any pressure-mounted gate I can put up here that's suitable for outdoor use? Or could I take an indoor gate and treat it somehow to make it suitable for outdoor use?

That one is going to be tough. Five year olds can climb.

Well, I hope she'll have better judgement by then, and I also will have installed better roof railings by then, too.

Are you at all concerned with her squeezing between the balusters?

Try a retractable indoor / outdoor baby gate  or may be a cargo net held up with carabiners.
No matter what you use you will need to attach something through the siding. Be it eye bolts or a 2x4 for other attchmentpoints. Carabiners or hooks can be held to the railing and handrail with zip ties. It's just the things we do to keep our kids safe.

How would I attach eye bolts or a 2x4 to the siding?

Perhaps you will need to hire a handyman for the install.   Generally there is a need to drill through the siding making small holes that can be filled and screwing into the wall sheeting behind the siding.

First off, anything you do will be temporary, and look kind of patched together.  On the left side, attach a baby gate to the railing with zip ties.  On the right side, take a couple scrap pieces of 2x4, and form am “ell”.   Clamp the short side of the 2x4 to the first stair so the vertical piece is above the front edge of the first stair, in the same plane as the zip tied baby gate.  Now you can attach the baby gate to the vertical part of the 2x4 “ell”.
Also, some netting on the left is a good idea.
Obviously, none of the above is a substitute for adult supervision.
Kids quickly get into “situations “.

Can also add some pink sill gasket between the upright and siding to minimize damage potential.

The siding does make a pressure-fit gate tricky.
I wouldn't worry much about using an indoor gate outdoors: you only need it to last a year or maybe two until the roof railing can be upgraded and/or the child may mature a bit. An indoor gate may be well-weathered by then, but there's a fair chance you'll get the value you needed from it.
As for mounting a swing-type gate, here's an idea. Use U-bolt hardware to attach a strip of wood (2x4 or similar) on two of the vertical rectangle tubes (balusters). Fasten the hinge of the gate to one of these strips with ordinary wood screw hardware -- to the one nearer to the bottom of the stairs, probably. In lieu of a latch on the siding side of the stairs, craft a removable diagonal brace which attaches to the second wood strip and to the gate frame. That'll prevent the gate swinging.
